# Parse XML and rename special char in filename (both XML and location)

Tags: xml, powershell, special-characters, rename, file-rename

I am in a situation of copying files from Unix to Windows. The files in Unix have special characters which Windows does not accept.

I have an XML file with tags for each of the files in location. This XML file will be passed in one of the applications to process.

1. Pick up one XML file.
2. Read through the attributes and find `<file>`.
3. Check if the value of the attribute has a special character.
4. Go to the next file if no special character. If the value has a special character - go to the location and rename the special character with valid ones (for example, rename `/` with `-`).
5. Do the same renaming in the XML file tag.
6. Go to the next file tag and pick up the next XML content.

I was thinking of doing it in PowerShell.

Sample XML:

```xml
<import>
    <node type="document" action="create">
        <location>XXXXXX</location>
        <title>log_0.log</title>
        <created>20190117</created>
        <file>\test*\log/0/.log</file>
    </node>
```

The `<File>` has two special characters in above sample... One is in the folder name (`*`) and thee other is in the filename (`//`).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add what code you have so far to your question. Then it will be much easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @kaspermoerch - i was trying to do seperately - unix and xml.

Unix.. i tried
shopt -s globstar
rename "s/\<>:?*[|]/_/g" **

xml i havn't figued out.. 

i do no thave any code at present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, adapt the following fragment for yourself.

```
$x=[xml]@'
<import>
  <node type="document" action="create">
    <location>XXXXXX</location>
    <title>log_0.log</title>
      <created>20190117</created>
      <file>\test*\log/0/.log</file>
  </node>
</import>
'@
$x.SelectNodes('/import/node/file') |
  ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.'#text'
    [char[]]$file |
      ForEach-Object {
        if( [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars() -contains $_ ) {
          $file = $file.Replace($_, '_')
        }
        if( $_ -ne [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar -and
            [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -contains $_ ) {
          $file = $file.Replace($_, '_')
        }
      }
    $file
  }
```

**Output:**

```
\test_\log_0_.log
```